# Representing a tinyint field as an enum in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've been using Linq2Sql for the last few years and got used to a few features, like having an `int` or `tinyint` field in the DB, that I redefine in the DBML file to be of enum type, so it's nice and convenient to run a SQL query directly comparing to the enum (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1007811/7850) for my question 3 years ago on the subject, and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1007872/7850) there).

Now I'm starting a project using Entity Framework 5, and while EF seems to have gotten many things right that L2S didn't (e.g. detach/reattach), I'm dismayed to see that there doesn't seem to be any easy way to change the C# type of such a field to be an enum.

Has anyone found a way to do this cleanly, so that I could have a query like:

```
var q = entities.Things.Where(t => t.Status == TStatus.Closed);
```

(and no, I don't want to have to cast to `int` or `byte` inline).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Code First**

EF5 Code First supports enum properties on .NET 4.5. The following entity will create a `int` field in the database:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public enum Status
{
    Open,
    Closed,
    Pending
}
```

To which you could query:

```
db.Events.Where(e => e.Status == Status.Pending)
```

**Database First**

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595008/enums-ef-5-0-database-first), here's how you accomplish the same thing for Database First.

> Go to the model browser and create a new enum type, then go to whatever column you wish to use it on and change its type to the enum that you just created.

Comment: Please note that it'd work only on .net 4.5 (while EF5 also runs on earlier versions).

Comment: Found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595008/enums-ef-5-0-database-first

Comment: I overheard that only difference in running EF5 CF between .net 4 and 4.5 is that in 4 it does not use new performance improvements

Comment: @DanielHilgarth by design. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574253): "When targeting .NET **4.5** this release [EF 5] introduces some new features including **enum support**, table-valued functions, spatial data types and various performance improvements."

Comment: @GoranObradovic I am sorry to disappoint, but you overheard wrong. See link above.

Comment: @JoeGennari - thanks for the link - that answered the question!  If you'll update your answer to show the solution for DB first, I'll give you answer credit.

Comment: Updated my answer with a Database First version.